# Applescript "can't get miniaturized of window"

Tags: applescript

I'm a beginner working on a script that counts windows in locations on screen. So far it works fairly well, although one flaw is it counts windows that are minimized.

Here is the working code currently:

```
tell application "System Events"
    set winCount1 to 0
    set winCount2 to 0
    set winCount3 to 0
    set winCount4 to 0
    set theProcesses to application processes
    repeat with theProcess from 1 to count theProcesses
        if visible of process theProcess is true then
            tell process theProcess
                repeat with x from 1 to (count windows)
                    if ((description of window x is not "dialog") then
                        set Pos to position of window x
                        if item 1 of Pos is less than -960 then
                            set winCount1 to winCount1 + 1
                        else if item 1 of Pos is less than 0 then
                            set winCount2 to winCount2 + 1
                        else if item 1 of Pos is less than 960 then
                            set winCount3 to winCount3 + 1
                        else
                            set winCount4 to winCount4 + 1
                        end if
                    end if
                end repeat
            end tell
        end if
    end repeat
    set countList to {winCount1, winCount2, winCount3, winCount4}
    return countList
end tell
```

Now to try to solve this issue, I tried adding a new condition:

```
if ((description of window x) is not "dialog") and window x is not miniaturized then
```

But this returns the error stated in the title. So I tried:

```
set props to get properties of window x
if props contains miniaturized then
```

This returns the same error.

I also tried:

```
set props to get properties of class of window x
if props contains miniaturized then
```

Same error.

It can't be that difficult to avoid windows without the miniaturized property before testing for it, but I'm not having luck finding a solution. Any ideas?

Comment: I regard this as a bug. Even the property `miniaturizable` throws an error. File it to Apple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the value of `attribute "AXMinimized"` of the window, like this:

```
set winCount1 to 0
set winCount2 to 0
set winCount3 to 0
set winCount4 to 0
tell application "System Events"
    repeat with theProcess in (application processes whose visible is true)
        tell theProcess
            repeat with thisWin in windows
                if (description of thisWin is not "dialog") and not (value of attribute "AXMinimized" of thisWin) then
                    set Pos to position of thisWin
                    if item 1 of Pos is less than -960 then
                        set winCount1 to winCount1 + 1
                    else if item 1 of Pos is less than 0 then
                        set winCount2 to winCount2 + 1
                    else if item 1 of Pos is less than 960 then
                        set winCount3 to winCount3 + 1
                    else
                        set winCount4 to winCount4 + 1
                    end if
                end if
            end repeat
        end tell
    end repeat
end tell
return {winCount1, winCount2, winCount3, winCount4}
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you for cleaning my code too.